# Properties from jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, properties, jquery-ui-datepicker

Maybe my question is very simple but didn't find answer. 
How to get properties from datepicker? 
Sample: In many places I set `minDate` to the datePicker field and I don't know what set there now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the manual](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option), to get the currently set value for `minDate`, you can use:

```
var minDate = $('#yourdatepickerid').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer document they have describe use of minDate http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range